# Computing an area of a parallelogram given the area of its planar projections

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

Let $\vec{v}, \vec{w} \in \mathbb{R}^3$. The length of their vector product, i.e. $|\vec{v} \times \vec{w}|$ equals the area of the parallelogram induced by $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$. This can be proven using some elementary, yet (for high school level) cumbersome algebra.

I want to prove it differently: If $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ have e.g. $v_z = w_z = 0$, then the above computation is very easy and for the area, we get $v_x w_y - v_y w_x =: A_{xy}$. This is what happens if we project the parallelogram onto the $xy$-plane.

Since this computation was so easy, I would like to now finish the proof by seeing that the area of the original parallelogram is $A = \sqrt{A_{xy}^2 + A_{xz}^2 + A_{yz}^2}$.

How can I prove the last equality?

I know the area and the projected area are related to each other via a factor of $\cos(\varphi)$, where $\varphi$ is the angle between the normal of the parallelogram and the normal of the projection plane, but applying this doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially [de Gua's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Gua%27s_theorem), applied to a triangle that's half of the parallelogram.

One proof of de Gua's theorem is to take a right tetrahedron with legs $a,b,c$ and apply Heron's formula to the area of the face with sides $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}, \sqrt{a^2+c^2}, \sqrt{b^2+c^2}$, but this doesn't let us get out of doing lots of algebra.

Maybe there are clever proofs out there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I googled for some different proofs of this theorem and found [this](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/pythagoras.shtml), which is very simple. Then, the equality follows by splitting the parallelogram up into four right-angled triangles. I guess this will suffice for me and I will have to think about whether this is a better approach for my high school students than the usual one. I like that the components of the vector product have a geometric meaning if I prove it this way, but it does take more time than the other, purely algebraic proof.